# How do I remove files from a range in a folder?

Tags: linux, bash

How do I delete a specific frame range in a folder?

I have

```
star_bg_true.0001.dpx
star_bg_true.0002.dpx
....
star_bg_true.0100.dpx
```

How do I remove only frames 0030–0050?

Answer (score 3):

With Bash 3, using [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace):

```
rm star_bg_true.00{30..50}.dpx
```

With Bash 4, you can do padded brace expansion:

```
rm star_bg_true.{0030..50}.dpx
```